# What is the formula needed to find possbile permutations in this specefic situation?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I need to find the possible permutations (hope that is the right terminology) given a set of items **N** where order is important and I'm looking for permutations with **M** number of consecutive items from **N** while also satisfying the condition that the number of pairings must be **P**.

An example of this would be having **N=4** items 1,2,3,4 and needing to pair these into **P=3** groups whil resepcting the order, this would give *[1 , 2-3,  4], [1-2  ,3  ,4], [1 ,  2 , 3-4]*.

**M** here can only be **1** or **2** if I have this right.

Comment: I don't think you mean permutations.  Permutations are are rearrangements, but you always keep the numbers in the same order.  I can't understand what you mean by $M$ and $P$.  You first say that $P$ is the number of pairings, and then that it is the number of groups.  Which is it?  What does "$M$ number of consecutive items" mean?  In the problem description, it sounds like $M$ is given, but in your example, you says it can be $1$ or $2$.  Please try to restate your question more clearly.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the answer, I struggled with putting the probelem into writing.
What I meant by P is the number of groups, in my example it is 3 so there has to be 3 groups of items, M I guess is not useful here but what I meant by it is that if we had 3 items in my example and P was 3 then M has to be 1. if N was 5 then M can be 3 since you can have [123,4,5]. M is useful for the specfic application I'm using this for since I want to be able to tune it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question what you have to do is choose $P-1$ places in the list
$$
1-2-3 - \cdots - N
$$
where you change the $-$ to a $,$ to build the list of groups (in your notation).

So the answer is the binomial coefficient $\binom{N-1}{P-1}$

For example, if $P=4$ and $N=7$ there will be $\binom{6}{3} = 20$ ways. One of them is
$$
1 - 2 , 3 - 4 - 5 , 6, 7
$$

You can look up [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) in wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you Ethan, I tried to look into this before posing here but I was a bit overwhelmed, I will read up on binomial coefficients. this does seem to answer the question, I'll just be left with the task of listing those possible ways.

Comment: @Alla Many computer languages have packages with methods that cab help with this.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input, I will look into those as well and I'm assuming adding the constraint of M is not possible or at least difficult, as in specifying that a group can not exceed M number of items, in your example setting M at 2 making the 2-3-4 group invalid.

Comment: @Alla With a maximum of $M$ in each group I think the problem is more difficult. (Your question did not make the meaning of $M$ clear.)

Comment: That is correct, I did not phrase it well, nonetheless your input has been valuable and I have an idea where to look for now.